# UIImage not passing from one ViewController to other

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I am trying to pass the image which is captured from `UIImagePickerController` to another `ViewController` but the image is not getting passed.

This is the code of the first `ViewController`:

```
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
{
    chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage 
    newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit 
    newImageView.image = chosenImage 

    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "pass", sender: self)

    dismiss(animated:true, completion: nil) 

    let svc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "demoViewController") as! demoViewController
   present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "pass"
    {
        let imgpass = segue.destination as! demoViewController
        imgpass.newphoto = chosenImage
    }
}
```

Code for the second `ViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    myImageView.image = newphoto
}
```

I went through a lot of other similar postings and implemented them too but couldn't get the image passed.

Comment: Can you add break point to this line and see the value of newphoto myImageView.image = newphoto ?

Comment: in your imagePickerController *func*: Why are you doing `performSegue` AND `present`? You should only do one of them. You can't go to 2 viewcontroller at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject])
    {
        if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

        newImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        newImageView.image = chosenImage

        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        let svc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "demoViewController") as! demoViewController
        svc.newphoto = chosenImage
        self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Comment: Good but you should _explain_.

Comment: it gives an error 'use of unresolved identifier 'imgpass''

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `func prepare(for:sender:)` implementation is never called, so your `newphoto` is never set. `prepare(for:sender:)` is sent before a segue. But there is no segue. You are presenting *in code*, not with a segue.

Comment: Also you should not be doing a `present` right after a `dismiss`. Do the `present` _in the completion handler_ of the `dismiss`.

Comment: on using "svc.imgpass = chosenImage" it gives error "Value of type 'demoViewController' has no member 'imgpass'"

Comment: Oh come on, you know what I mean. Do some thinking on your own. Don't make us tie your shoes for you.

Comment: @VaibhavArora it means `demoViewController` *doesn't* have a property/member/instance variable that is named `imgPass`. Make sure it has one! Though as Matt mentioned this is a fairly simple error to understand...